# uninitialized constant Encoding::UTF_8 (NameError) when run shopify-cli (ruby gem)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I have installed the shopify-cli tool using `gem install shopify-cli` as advised in the shopify.dev docs. However, although it is installed along with dependencies, when I try to run it e.g. `shopify version` then it doesn't work.
I get:

```
.gem/gems/shopify-cli-2.2.0/lib/shopify_cli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Encoding::UTF_8 (NameError)'
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Ruby 3.0.2 (installed as a Snap).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gem.

Comment: I would suggest trying some older ruby version like 2.7.3. Ruby version managers are useful in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the suggestion in the above comment by J Krzus.
I removed the Snap version of Ruby (3.0.2) and then used rbenv to install Ruby 2.7.4 and reinstalled the gem with that.
Shopify-cli is now working properly.